# Assign business account record type for enabling person accounts

Tags: person-accounts

I am currently trying to enable Person Account Type. I have followed the steps mentioned in the relating guide and submited the issue to customer service.

But now they bug me a lot, with really non-understandable emails like this:

> " have checked and currently there is no Business Account Record Type
>   created yet for the org you requested. Once I have your confirmation
>   that Business Account record type has been created, I will forward
>   this request to our Senior Engineers for their approval."

Well, I already have plenty of Account Record Types. What do they mean with Business Account Record Type? Should I just name it like that or what's the catch?

I wouldn't have thought that it is THAT hard to skip accounts for individuals.

You got any advice on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we created our org we added a Record Type called "Business Accout" and then requested Person Accounts be activated. You don't have to assign the Record Type to any of your profiles so I would just go ahead and create it. I'm pretty sure you can delete it afterward, if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

A Business Account is a standard (b2b) account which pertains to Accounts as we know them. A Person account is the B2C variant.

This excerpt from salesforce docs kinda helps:

"Record types are person account record types if the Account field IsPersonAccount is set to true. Salesforce provides one default person account record type, PersonAccount, but an administrator can create additional person account record types. Conversely, record types with the Account field IsPersonAccount set to false are “business account” record types, which are traditional business-to-business (B2B) Salesforce accounts"

Source : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_guidelines_personaccounts.htm